# How to launch Cowboy on 0.0.0.0 in Elixir?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, cowboy

I am using Exrm to deploy my Phoenix app. I have configured my application to bind to `0.0.0.0` in my `config/prod.exs`:

```
config :apiServer, ApiServer.Endpoint,
  http: [ip: {0, 0, 0, 0}, port: 4000],
  url: [host: "sitenamehere.co", port: 4000],
  cache_static_manifest: "priv/static/manifest.json",
  root: ".",
  cache_static_manifest: "priv/static/manifest.json",
  server: true,
  version: Mix.Project.config[:version]
```

However, when I run my release, I get:

`Running ApiServer.Endpoint with Cowboy using http://localhost:4000`

, when it should be `0.0.0.0`. Help?

Comment: Have you actually checked what your server is bound to?

Comment: @pvg I'm not sure I follow. :/

Comment: You know, run netstat or whatever your favourite tools is to check what interfaces are listening on port 4000. It's probably not a good idea to bind to everything anyway but you can easily check.

Answer (score 2):

The value logged was changed in [this pull request](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/pull/1818/files).

Which should be present in Phoenix version 1.2.1 and later. Could you confirm which version of Phoenix you are using?

Prior to that pull request, the value would always show `localhost` in the logs, but http://0.0.0.0:4000 would work.

This following commits are also historically relevant to this issue:

- https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/commit/de1fd9ff280d9a898a7453cf3bef5cfa35492339
- https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/commit/ecd84f283f0203163b1f864747e1d0acd5aeca64